# Bottom Navigation Bar Overflows

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

The bottom of my navigation bar goes out to the left too much. Please help!

Here is my html:

```
<div id="bottem">

  <h4>Made by xyz 2016</h4>
  <h5>With lots of help from Develop Academy </h5>
  <h5><a href="info.html" id="info">More Info</a></h5>

</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
#bottem {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(51, 126, 198, 0.28);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

here is my website:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy9XM.jpg)

Comment: ...You mean "goes out to the right"?

Answer (score 1):

Use css `padding` property like in the code below. `padding` property are use for generating space around it's content from left side. If you want to generate the space from all directions,then just use `padding` only eg. `padding:20px`.

```css
#bottem {
  padding:5px 20px; /*5px = top & bottom, 20px = left & right;*/
  background-color: rgba(51, 126, 198, 0.28);
}
```

```html
<div id="bottem">

  <h4>Made by xyz 2016</h4>
  <h5>With lots of help from Develop Academy </h5>
  <h5><a href="info.html" id="info">More Info</a></h5>

</div>
```

Comment: padding made the overflow larger

Comment: @xXWONTONXx To fix the overflow, add `box-sizing: border-box;` or remove `width: 100%;` and `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to have an inner element that can be padded without contributing to the width of the outer element.

```css
#bottom {
  background-color: rgba(51, 126, 198, 0.28);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
#bottom-inner {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(51, 126, 198, 0.28);
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">
  <div id="bottom-inner">
    <h4>Made by xyz 2016</h4>
    <h5>With lots of help from Develop Academy </h5>
    <h5><a href="info.html" id="info">More Info</a></h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your width at 100%, your padding just makes the width bigger. That's why it's overflowing. You can get rid of your padding. Or you can set your width using pixels.

Or you can set width and padding using px or %. Just make sure they add up to 100. Read about the box model here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

padding: 5%;
width: 90%;

Comment: try this:  #bottem {
  background-color: rgba(51, 126, 198, 0.28);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5%;
  width: 90%;
}

Answer (score 0):

This is a really easy fix haha.

You have your margin left and right set to 10px, but elements have their own natural margin. The other answers do solve some of those issues, but to keep a div centered it is best to just use

```
margin:0 auto;
```

this will have the browser eliminate the top and bottom margins and calculate the rest to keep your div centered in the viewport.

Also, if this does not solve your issue please give more details.

Another question I have, is why do you have it set to inline-block?